# How to clone a jQuery Chosen select box with dynamically populated options?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, clone

I'm facing issues while cloning an existing chosen element (not the options but the entire select box) and creating a dynamic id for them.

I'm able to clone the chosen element however, it has the same id generated as that of parent chosen and is not allowing to select an option in there.

When I click on the newly generated chosen box, the parent chosen that was cloned is showing the list of options to select instead of child chosen. Child chosen was made frozen and I'm unable to select the options in it.

Screenshot:

[image]

JS:

```
$("#addCostDetailsRowBtn").button().click(addCostRowFn);

var addCostRowFn = function () {
var rowLen = $(".costTemplateRow").length;
//alert(rowLen);
var $newRow = $("#costTemplateRow1").clone(true);
$newRow.find('select').each(function () {
    //alert($(this));
    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
    var item = $(this).attr('id');
    if('undefined'!=item) {
        var newItem = item.replace(/^(.*)(\d+)$/, function(match, p1, p2) {
            return p1+(parseInt(p2)+1);
        });
        $(this).attr('id', newItem);
        $(this).removeClass("chzn-done");

    }
});

$('#costsTable tr:last').before($newRow);
return false;
};
```

Can someone please help me get the issue resolved?

Thanks,
Jaya Krishna

Comment: Is there a reason you need to clone the element Chosen generates? What about cloning the <select> element and then applying Chosen to it with the same options?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Yes, I tried that.. but for some reason I'm unable to apply the class (chzn-select) on top of it.
`code`
var $newRow = $("#costTemplateRow").clone(true);
 var rowLen = $(".costTemplateRow").length;
 $newRow.find('select').each(function (){
  var curId = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).attr('id',curId+rowLen);
  $(this).attr('class','chzn-select');
  
 });
 $newRow.show();
 
 $('#costsTable tr:last').before($newRow);
`code`

Comment: Thanks, I tried cloning a plain select drop-down and then applied 'chosen' style on top of that. I was not calling the update list event on chosen class hence, was not working before. Thanks for your inputs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the clone is still sharing some data with the original object. From the Jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional withDataAndEvents parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element. As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy.

However, objects and arrays within element data are not copied and will continue to be shared between the cloned element and the original element. To deep copy all data, copy each one manually:

```
var $elem = $('#elem').data( "arr": [ 1 ] ), // Original element with attached data
$clone = $elem.clone( true )
.data( "arr", $.extend( [], $elem.data("arr") ) ); // Deep copy to prevent data sharing
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Chosen generates supporting elements like <a>, <ul> internally and their ids not getting modified every time I add a new row. However, I avoided cloning a styled (chosen class) select box but cloning a plain drop-down, adding a new id and then tried applying the chosen style which worked perfect. Thanks again for your inputs.

Comment: this is a direct paste from the JQuery docs and doesn't say much about chosen

Answer (score 0):

ok then, here is what I did to clone a chosen control with dynamic populated options.  Maybe a better way, but without more info on jquery cache/cloning this at least works.

```
var $parent = $('#myThingParentNode');
var clonePropDdl = $parent.find('.chosenProperty').clone();
//get selected value of chosen venue control
var clonePropDdlVal = $venue.find('.chosenProperty').val();
//find the element to add the new Chosen control
var $newCloneElem = $('#newPropCloneElement');
//add the new clone
$newCloneElem.append(clonePropDdl);
//initialize the clone
$newCloneElem.chosen({ width: "150px" });
//delete the cloned chosen detritis!! This is what makes this work
**$newCloneElem.find('.chosen-container:eq(1)').remove();**
//set the selected value of the new clone to value of the clone source
$newCloneElem.val(lastVenueVal).trigger('chosen:updated');
```