# jquery chosen plugin doesn't work after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm facing issues while cloning an existing chosen element. 
chosen clone element doesn't work. I am not able to access chosen select box. 
In the first time it works
[image]

But When I clone this element Then cloned element doesn't work.
[image]

**This is the code what I tried**

```
$("#add_more_item").click(function() {
    $("table#tbl_main tr:last").clone()
                .attr( 'id', function() { return this.id + 1; })
                .find(':text')
                .val('')
                .end()
                .appendTo('table#tbl_main tbody');
});
```

I have read this question [How to clone a jQuery Chosen select box with dynamically populated options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153639/how-to-clone-a-jquery-chosen-select-box-with-dynamically-populated-options) but i didn't find what I need.

Comment: Why cloning it? Why not call plugin on new elements?

Comment: @A.Wolff actually I clone the full `tr`

Comment: Ya but you could still create a new TR with relevant elements inside but that really depends of how you set initial TR. Otherwise, you could clone TR, remove specific class/data relative to chosen for these elements and then recall on it chosen plugin